# Is it possible to have a Nuxt install on Top level domain and WP install on a subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js, subdomain, netlify

Is it possible to have a Nuxt installation hosted on Netlify on the top-level domain, and a WordPress installation hosted on Siteground on a subdomain? The DNS service used is Hover.

To clarify, this is how it should be setup:

- `examplesite.com` (this would be a Nuxt install on Netlify, with IP address on the A record pointed to Netlify's servers)
- `rsvp.examplesite.com` (this would be a WordPress install on Siteground)

Is this achievable? Ideally it wouldn't be a redirect unless the URL stays the same in the bar the entire time. I don't want users to panic if they see a junk URL because it just redirects them.

Thanks in advance!